# По каким причинам могут не работать меди запросы?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, media-queries

Почему могут не работать медиа запросы? Делаю все как положено: сами запросы всегда идут в конце документа, написаны без ошибок `@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {}` уже даже пробовал подключать их отдельным файлом после основного. Но все равно на указанных разрешениях они не то чтобы не применяются а их в принципе нет.

```css
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

.otziv_wrapper {
 margin: 80px 0;
 font-family: "firasans";
}

.otziv_block {
 position: relative;
/* border-radius: 15px;
 border-left: 7px solid;
 border-bottom: 7px solid;
 border-color: #0086a9;*/
 background: #fff;
}

.otziv_preview {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 190px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.otziv_preview:before {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 width: 515px;
 height: 203px;
 position: absolute;
 top: -7px;
 left: 0;
 background-image: url("../img/img-line_1.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.otziv_preview:after {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 width: 370px;
 height: 103px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -102px;
 right: 55px;
 background-image: url("../img/img-line_2.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.otziv_preview-img {
 position: absolute;
 left: 60px;
 bottom: 0;
}

.otziv_preview-text {
 max-width: 490px;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 24px;
 color: #000;
 float: right;
}

.otziv_step1 {
 position: relative;
 margin: 70px 0 75px;
}

.otziv_step1:after {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 width: 376px;
 height: 118px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 51px;
 bottom: -75px;
 background-image: url("../img/img-line_3.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.otziv_step1-text {
 max-width: 510px;
 margin-left: 40px;
}

.otziv_step-text-title {
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.otziv_step-text-name {
 font-size: 16px;
}

.otziv_step-text-item {
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 20px;
 padding-right: 40px;
}

.otziv_step1-img {
 position: absolute;
 right: 150px;
 top: -39px;
}

.otziv_step-loc {
 position: absolute;
 width: 147px;
 height: 187px;
 text-align: center;
 background-image: url("../img/img_location.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}

.otziv_step1-loc_pos {
 top: -25px;
 right: -13px;
}

.otziv_step-loc_text {
 margin-top: 35px;
 font-family: "firasansmedium";
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #29507a;
 line-height: 24px;
 letter-spacing: -0.12em;
}

.otziv_step-loc_num {
 font-family: "firasansmedium";
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 13px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -7px;
}

.otziv_step2 {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.otziv_step2:before {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 83px;
 top: -7px;
 width: 430px;
 height: 103px;
 background-image: url(../img/img-line_4.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.otziv_step2-video {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 100;
 left: 180px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -70px;
 width: 270px;
 height: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.otziv_step2-video_text-wr {
 padding: 5px;
}

.otziv_step2-video_text {
 margin-bottom: 3px;
 font-size: 8px;
 color: #141414;
}

.otziv_step2-video_subscribe {
 font-size: 8px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 2px 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #ff2d02;
}

.otziv_step2-video_subscribe:hover {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.otziv_icon-yt {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 11px;
 height: 6px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-top: -2px;
 background-image: url(../img/icon_yt.png);
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}

.otziv_step2-text {
 float: right;
 max-width: 430px;
}

.otziv_step2-loc_pos {
 left: 15px;
 top: 45px;
}

.otziv_step3 {
 padding-top: 95px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.otziv_step3:after {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 78px;
 top: -126px;
 width: 378px;
 height: 116px;
 background-image: url(../img/img-line_5.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.otziv_step3:before {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: -17px;
 right: 55px;
 width: 430px;
 height: 103px;
 background-image: url(../img/img-line_6.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.otziv_step3-loc_pos {
 right: -14px;
 top: 43px;
}

.otziv_step3-text {
 max-width: 440px;
 margin-left: 50px;
}

.otziv_step3-item {
 font-size: 18px;
}

.otziv_step3-email-wr {
 position: absolute;
 right: 135px;
 top: 40px;
 text-align: center;
}

.otziv_step3-email {
 font-family: "firasansbold";
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #004f7c;
 letter-spacing: -0.08em;
}

.otziv_step3-email-icon {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.otziv_get-gift {
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-family: "firasansbold";
 font-size: 80px;
 color: #cf2712;
 text-align: center;
}

.otziv_get-gift:before {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 right: 49px;
 top: -100px;
 width: 86px;
 height: 146px;
 background-image: url(../img/img-line_7.png);
}

.otziv_forma-wr {
 margin-top: 70px;
}

.otziv_forma {
 width: 615px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 35px 55px;
 border: 6px solid #0086a9;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.otziv_forma-input {
 width: 240px;
 height: 35px;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
 border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.otziv_forma-input::placeholder {
 color: #bbbbbb;
}

.otziv_forma-input:nth-child(odd) {
 float: left;
}

.otziv_forma-input:nth-child(even) {
 float: right;
}

.otziv_forma-button {
 display: block;
 width: 240px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: "firasansbold";
 font-size: 16px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 border: none;
 background-color: #0076b0;
}

.some_test {
 background-color: #ccc;
}

@media screen and(max-width: 992px) {

 .some_test {
  background-color: #ff00ca;
 }
  
  .otziv_wrapper {
    background: green;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Otziv</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssnew/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/otziv_grid.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/otziv_style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="some_test">Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Что назад жизни запятой составитель безорфографичный родного всеми возвращайся пояс деревни они использовало предупреждал даже мир, реторический маленькая, бросил грустный.</div>
 
 <div class="otziv_wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="otziv_block otziv_preview">
    <img src="img/img-1.png" alt="" class="otziv_preview-img">
    <div class="otziv_preview-text">Выполните всего три действия, и получите сертификат* на покупку в интернет-магазине  avantsb.ru на сумму от 1000 руб. Для этого Вам нужно выполнить 3 условия.</div>
   </div>
   <div class="otziv_block otziv_step1">
    <div class="otziv_step1-text">
     <div class="otziv_step-text-title">1. Записать мини обзор на квадроцикл Avantis или ATV Classic</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">Видео должно содержать:</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- проговорено полное название квадроцикла</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- возраст ребенка (детей), для которого был приобретен <br />
     квадроцикл</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- демонстрация поездки ребенка на квадроцикле <br />
     (желательно в защитной экипировке)</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- поделитесь своими впечатлениями от использования <br />
     квадроцикла Avantis (от взрослого и ребенка)</div>
    </div>
    <img src="img/img-2.png" alt="" class="otziv_step1-img">
    <div class="otziv_step-loc otziv_step1-loc_pos">
     <div class="otziv_step-loc_text">Запиши видео о квадроцикле Avantis</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-loc_num">1</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="otziv_block otziv_step2 clearfix">
    <div class="otziv_step-loc otziv_step2-loc_pos">
     <div class="otziv_step-loc_text">Опубликуй  видео <br />на своем <br />youtube-канале</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-loc_num">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="otziv_step2-video">
     <iframe width="270px" height="190px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UwtqfCbWDo4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     <div class="otziv_step2-video_text-wr">
      <div class="otziv_step2-video_text">Модель квадроцикла (пример: Отзыв о квадроцикле Avantis mirage 8)</div>
      <a href="#" class="otziv_step2-video_subscribe"><i class="otziv_icon-yt"></i>Подписаться</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="otziv_step2-text">
     <div class="otziv_step-text-title">2. Опубликовать видео на Вашем канале youtube с подписью: </div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">Название видео:</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- Модель квадроцикла (пример: Отзыв о квадроцикле Avantis Mirage 8)</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">Описание видео:</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- название квадроцикла (квадроцикл Avantis Mirage 8)</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- ссылка на наш сайт: http://www.avantsb.ru</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- ссылка на наш канал на youtube: https://www.youtube.com/user/MyAvantis»</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="otziv_block otziv_step3">
    <div class="otziv_step-loc otziv_step3-loc_pos">
     <div class="otziv_step-loc_text">Запиши видео о <br />квадроцикле Avantis</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-loc_num">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="otziv_step3-text">
     <div class="otziv_step3-item">3. Отправить ссылку на видео нам на почту <br /><br />* Сертификат может быть использован только один раз. Он не подлежит возврату и обмену на деньги ни полностью, ни частично. Разница суммы, оставшаяся после покупки, не возвращается. Если стоимость выбранных товаров выше номинала сертификата, разницу нужно доплатить .</div>
    </div>
    <div class="otziv_step3-email-wr">
     <div class="otziv_step3-email">otzyv@avantismotors.ru</div>
     <img src="img/img-3.png" alt="" class="otziv_step3-email-icon">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="otziv_block otziv_get-gift">
    Получи подарок
   </div>
   <div class="otziv_forma-wr">
    <form action="#" class="otziv_forma clearfix">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" class="otziv_forma-input">
     <input type="text" pattern="\d [0-9]" placeholder="Телефон" class="otziv_forma-input">
     <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="otziv_forma-input">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Ссылка на видео" class="otziv_forma-input">
     <button class="otziv_forma-button">Отправить</button>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: приведи [mcve].

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev еще скажи у тебя используется на сайте минификаторы для `css`?

Comment: Как вариант не в том порядке идут запросы

Comment: А ты уверен, что у тебя окно не больше чем 1200px?

Comment: @Grundy Ну вот примерно такой вариант у меня не отрабатывает ни в одном браузере. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev, сниппет работает как и задумалось, для маленького экрана маленький текст для большого - большой

Comment: @Grundy я вижу что здесь он работает, но на моем пк увы нет, поэтому и спрашиваю в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Очевидно проблема в твоих остальных стилях.

Comment: Что же в остальных стилях может быть такого что блокирует выполнение медиа запросов?

Comment: Интересно кто такой умный минусует ответ и не приводит причини, просто интересно , отзовись и скажи в чем ошибка?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, твои завистники :D

Comment: _Что же в остальных стилях может быть такого что блокирует выполнение медиа запросов?_ - что угодно, без примера, который _воспроизводит_ проблему можно только гадать, что и как у тебя работает

Comment: @Yuri ну вот и я об этом, надо в лицо узнать врага)))

Comment: В ходе тестов отключил все дополнительные стили включая основные, проблема сохранилась, возможно что то не так в разметке, но займусь этим чуть позже, сейчас времени нету((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь ваш код работает, поскольку здесь на сайте добавлен `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`.

Вот два примера можете на голом `html` файле посмотреть.

Первый использованием `meta viewport` и с ним `media` запросы работают нормально.

```
<style>    
    body{
        background: black;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        body{
            background: red;
        }
    }
</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Это скрин с `viewport`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А второй пример вот так, просто уберем `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`, и уже `media` запрос не работает.

```
<style>    
    body{
        background: black;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        body{
            background: red;
        }
    }
</style>
```

А это без `viewport`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь подробно описано про [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Ну надо же так? ))))
Вы написали так `@media screen and(max-width: 992px)`,  а надо вот так `@media screen and (max-width: 992px)`, пробел после `and`

```css
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

.otziv_wrapper {
 margin: 80px 0;
 font-family: "firasans";
}

.otziv_block {
 position: relative;
/* border-radius: 15px;
 border-left: 7px solid;
 border-bottom: 7px solid;
 border-color: #0086a9;*/
 background: #fff;
}

.otziv_preview {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 190px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.otziv_preview:before {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 width: 515px;
 height: 203px;
 position: absolute;
 top: -7px;
 left: 0;
 background-image: url("../img/img-line_1.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.otziv_preview:after {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 width: 370px;
 height: 103px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -102px;
 right: 55px;
 background-image: url("../img/img-line_2.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.otziv_preview-img {
 position: absolute;
 left: 60px;
 bottom: 0;
}

.otziv_preview-text {
 max-width: 490px;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 24px;
 color: #000;
 float: right;
}

.otziv_step1 {
 position: relative;
 margin: 70px 0 75px;
}

.otziv_step1:after {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 width: 376px;
 height: 118px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 51px;
 bottom: -75px;
 background-image: url("../img/img-line_3.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.otziv_step1-text {
 max-width: 510px;
 margin-left: 40px;
}

.otziv_step-text-title {
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.otziv_step-text-name {
 font-size: 16px;
}

.otziv_step-text-item {
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 20px;
 padding-right: 40px;
}

.otziv_step1-img {
 position: absolute;
 right: 150px;
 top: -39px;
}

.otziv_step-loc {
 position: absolute;
 width: 147px;
 height: 187px;
 text-align: center;
 background-image: url("../img/img_location.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}

.otziv_step1-loc_pos {
 top: -25px;
 right: -13px;
}

.otziv_step-loc_text {
 margin-top: 35px;
 font-family: "firasansmedium";
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #29507a;
 line-height: 24px;
 letter-spacing: -0.12em;
}

.otziv_step-loc_num {
 font-family: "firasansmedium";
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 13px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -7px;
}

.otziv_step2 {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.otziv_step2:before {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 83px;
 top: -7px;
 width: 430px;
 height: 103px;
 background-image: url(../img/img-line_4.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.otziv_step2-video {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 100;
 left: 180px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -70px;
 width: 270px;
 height: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 1px solid #b8b8b8;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.otziv_step2-video_text-wr {
 padding: 5px;
}

.otziv_step2-video_text {
 margin-bottom: 3px;
 font-size: 8px;
 color: #141414;
}

.otziv_step2-video_subscribe {
 font-size: 8px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 2px 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #ff2d02;
}

.otziv_step2-video_subscribe:hover {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.otziv_icon-yt {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 11px;
 height: 6px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-top: -2px;
 background-image: url(../img/icon_yt.png);
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}

.otziv_step2-text {
 float: right;
 max-width: 430px;
}

.otziv_step2-loc_pos {
 left: 15px;
 top: 45px;
}

.otziv_step3 {
 padding-top: 95px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.otziv_step3:after {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 78px;
 top: -126px;
 width: 378px;
 height: 116px;
 background-image: url(../img/img-line_5.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.otziv_step3:before {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: -17px;
 right: 55px;
 width: 430px;
 height: 103px;
 background-image: url(../img/img-line_6.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.otziv_step3-loc_pos {
 right: -14px;
 top: 43px;
}

.otziv_step3-text {
 max-width: 440px;
 margin-left: 50px;
}

.otziv_step3-item {
 font-size: 18px;
}

.otziv_step3-email-wr {
 position: absolute;
 right: 135px;
 top: 40px;
 text-align: center;
}

.otziv_step3-email {
 font-family: "firasansbold";
 font-size: 40px;
 color: #004f7c;
 letter-spacing: -0.08em;
}

.otziv_step3-email-icon {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.otziv_get-gift {
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-family: "firasansbold";
 font-size: 80px;
 color: #cf2712;
 text-align: center;
}

.otziv_get-gift:before {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 right: 49px;
 top: -100px;
 width: 86px;
 height: 146px;
 background-image: url(../img/img-line_7.png);
}

.otziv_forma-wr {
 margin-top: 70px;
}

.otziv_forma {
 width: 615px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 35px 55px;
 border: 6px solid #0086a9;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.otziv_forma-input {
 width: 240px;
 height: 35px;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
 border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.otziv_forma-input::placeholder {
 color: #bbbbbb;
}

.otziv_forma-input:nth-child(odd) {
 float: left;
}

.otziv_forma-input:nth-child(even) {
 float: right;
}

.otziv_forma-button {
 display: block;
 width: 240px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: "firasansbold";
 font-size: 16px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 border: none;
 background-color: #0076b0;
}

.some_test {
 background-color: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {

 .some_test {
  background-color: #ff00ca;
 }
  
  .otziv_wrapper {
    background: green;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Otziv</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssnew/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/otziv_grid.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/otziv_style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="some_test">Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Что назад жизни запятой составитель безорфографичный родного всеми возвращайся пояс деревни они использовало предупреждал даже мир, реторический маленькая, бросил грустный.</div>
 
 <div class="otziv_wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="otziv_block otziv_preview">
    <img src="img/img-1.png" alt="" class="otziv_preview-img">
    <div class="otziv_preview-text">Выполните всего три действия, и получите сертификат* на покупку в интернет-магазине  avantsb.ru на сумму от 1000 руб. Для этого Вам нужно выполнить 3 условия.</div>
   </div>
   <div class="otziv_block otziv_step1">
    <div class="otziv_step1-text">
     <div class="otziv_step-text-title">1. Записать мини обзор на квадроцикл Avantis или ATV Classic</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">Видео должно содержать:</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- проговорено полное название квадроцикла</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- возраст ребенка (детей), для которого был приобретен <br />
     квадроцикл</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- демонстрация поездки ребенка на квадроцикле <br />
     (желательно в защитной экипировке)</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- поделитесь своими впечатлениями от использования <br />
     квадроцикла Avantis (от взрослого и ребенка)</div>
    </div>
    <img src="img/img-2.png" alt="" class="otziv_step1-img">
    <div class="otziv_step-loc otziv_step1-loc_pos">
     <div class="otziv_step-loc_text">Запиши видео о квадроцикле Avantis</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-loc_num">1</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="otziv_block otziv_step2 clearfix">
    <div class="otziv_step-loc otziv_step2-loc_pos">
     <div class="otziv_step-loc_text">Опубликуй  видео <br />на своем <br />youtube-канале</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-loc_num">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="otziv_step2-video">
     <iframe width="270px" height="190px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UwtqfCbWDo4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     <div class="otziv_step2-video_text-wr">
      <div class="otziv_step2-video_text">Модель квадроцикла (пример: Отзыв о квадроцикле Avantis mirage 8)</div>
      <a href="#" class="otziv_step2-video_subscribe"><i class="otziv_icon-yt"></i>Подписаться</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="otziv_step2-text">
     <div class="otziv_step-text-title">2. Опубликовать видео на Вашем канале youtube с подписью: </div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">Название видео:</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- Модель квадроцикла (пример: Отзыв о квадроцикле Avantis Mirage 8)</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">Описание видео:</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- название квадроцикла (квадроцикл Avantis Mirage 8)</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- ссылка на наш сайт: http://www.avantsb.ru</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-text-item">- ссылка на наш канал на youtube: https://www.youtube.com/user/MyAvantis»</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="otziv_block otziv_step3">
    <div class="otziv_step-loc otziv_step3-loc_pos">
     <div class="otziv_step-loc_text">Запиши видео о <br />квадроцикле Avantis</div>
     <div class="otziv_step-loc_num">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="otziv_step3-text">
     <div class="otziv_step3-item">3. Отправить ссылку на видео нам на почту <br /><br />* Сертификат может быть использован только один раз. Он не подлежит возврату и обмену на деньги ни полностью, ни частично. Разница суммы, оставшаяся после покупки, не возвращается. Если стоимость выбранных товаров выше номинала сертификата, разницу нужно доплатить .</div>
    </div>
    <div class="otziv_step3-email-wr">
     <div class="otziv_step3-email">otzyv@avantismotors.ru</div>
     <img src="img/img-3.png" alt="" class="otziv_step3-email-icon">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="otziv_block otziv_get-gift">
    Получи подарок
   </div>
   <div class="otziv_forma-wr">
    <form action="#" class="otziv_forma clearfix">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" class="otziv_forma-input">
     <input type="text" pattern="\d [0-9]" placeholder="Телефон" class="otziv_forma-input">
     <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="otziv_forma-input">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Ссылка на видео" class="otziv_forma-input">
     <button class="otziv_forma-button">Отправить</button>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну вот у меня примерно такая же история, абсолютно не отрабатывает медиа запрос (как у вас на втором скрине) только вот meta viewport у меня есть и более того именно его я копировал для вставки в пример вопроса.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev что бы понять в чем причина просто не на голом `html` а на своем сайте добавьте простой `div` с уникальным классом и дайте ему эти стили. если заработает значит у вас стили перекрывают друг друга. а если не заработает пойдем дальше тестировать.

Comment: По вашему совету так же тестил, но результат идентичный, стили через медиа запросы попросту не применяются (их будто вообще нет). Чуть позже выложу свой код, чтобы вам нагляднее было.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev а ты уверен что твои изменения браузер принял? и еще дай в вопросе все `meta` свойство твоего сайта.

Comment: Кстати шапка из текущего примера полностью из моего документа, поэтому других meta тегов там нет.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev ну значит надо полный код страницы

Comment: Добавил полный код в вопрос, без изображений и некоторых стилей выглядит правда стремно, но думаю суть не в этом.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev и еще одно, у тебя на сайте минификатор есть?

Comment: @Ramzik Galstyan нет

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev Проблема решена.

Comment: Черт возьми я пол дня промучался с этим вот, а проблема была в долбаном пробеле. Помню когда то уже сталкивался с таким же, но это было настолько давно что я и забыл уже. Благодарю вас, сам бы ломал голову еще долго))